# How to determine if CSS3DObject is seen from backside or frontside?

Tags: three.js, webgl

[image]

I tried to use `CSS3DRenderer` to transform my DIVs，but I encountered this problem.

Because `CSS3DRenderer` is totally based on `HTML`, so it just doesn't act like what `WebglRenderer` does.(`WebglRenderer` can identify Backside and FrontSide)

I did try to identify Backside or FrontSide by testing the dot product of `CSS3DObject` direction and camera direction.

```js
const objectToward = object.getWorldDirection(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    const cameraToward = base.camera.instance.getWorldDirection(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    console.log(objectToward.dot(cameraToward))
```

But I found this way is still not perfect, because I am using perspective camera.

(I  can still see the `CSS3DObject` even the directions are orthogonal, just like the picture above.)

I just need to know how to identify Backside or FrontSide even if the scene is rendered in perspective way.

Comment: For some ideas, read this forum thread: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/html-on-different-faces-of-cube/17281

Comment: this one seems viable, will take a try, thanks! 
@prisoner849

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to perform all the calculations you're trying. In order to hide the HTML element when it's facing away, you can simply apply the following CSS property to it:

```css
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

This will automatically not render the object when its face rotates away from the camera. [See here for more information on that CSS rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility)

Comment: Sounds good,  but still not working...

Comment: I also added transform-style="preserve-3d" btw,  but no luck.

Comment: I dunno why, maybe it was bc `three.js` is using transform: matrix() to do the 3d rotation  instead of using rotate (I am not sure)

Comment: I’d need to see a live demo then. Maybe a https://jsfiddle.net demo so I can look at which part is causing the issue.

Comment: Ok, but actually I had already solve the problem by taking the solution from @prisoner849.

here is my site : 

https://mizok.github.io/3d-Cube-Chat/

Comment: Sorry it's too big I can't just put it on jsfiddle. :(